# Why my selection sort is slower than insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I'm trying to write the implementations for selection sort and insertion sort. And tested them with an auto generated array and evaluates the time consuming with Posix `gettimeofday` in u-second accuracy, under `MAC OS`.

But in most case, with an total `65525` and range from `-65525` and `+65525` input array, the insertion sort is far faster than selection sort, says about half of time.

implementation see below:

```
void selectionSort (vector<int>& ns) {
uint_t j, minInd; 
for (uint_t i = 0; i< ns.size() - 1; i++) {
    j = i + 1;         
    minInd = i;
    while (j < ns.size()) {
        if(ns[j] < ns[minInd])
           minInd = j; 
        j++;
    }
    if (minInd != i) {
        int tmp = ns[minInd];
        ns[minInd] = ns[i];
        ns[i] = tmp;
    }
    }
} 

insertSort (vector<int>& ns){
       for(int i = 1; i < (int)ns.size(); i++) {
       int key = ns[i]; 
       int j = i - 1;
       for( ; j >= 0; j--) {
           if (ns[j] > key ) {
               ns[j+1] = ns[j]; 
           } else {
               break;
           }
       }
       ns[j+1] = key;
    }
}
```

Some Test results:

**Insert Sort:**

> Min=(-65524), index=(89660); Max=(62235), index=(23486) 
>   ShowSysTime millisecond: 1447749079447950, diff time to last record:**20092583**
>   Min=(-65524), index=(0); Max=(62235), index=(131050)

**Selection Sort:**

> Min=(-65524), index=(89660); Max=(62235), index=(23486) 
>   ShowSysTime millisecond: 1447749114384115, diff time to last record:**34934768**
>   Min=(-65524), index=(0); Max=(62235), index=(131050)

The insertion sort is from book ITA, so I suspect my selection sort has something not correct.

Comment: Selection sort is almost by definition slower than insertion sort, so it's not a surprising result indicating something wrong, but expected.

Comment: @harold . Even I came here to write that. You beat me to it :P

Comment: Wiki article [selection sort compared to other sorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Comparison_to_other_sorting_algorithms) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) is a simple but inefficient sorting algorithm. It has always quadratic complexity, in the worst case as well as in the best case.

On the other hand, [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) is quadratic at worst but linear at best.  Therefore it is expected that, in some cases, it will perform better than selection sort.  It would be surprising the opposite.

Comment: Noted: don't forget about Ω(n)

Answer (score 1):

In all the cases of selection sort, a selected value is compared with all other not sorted values. Hence, time complexity is always quadratic or n^2.

Where as in Insertion Sort, in best case it was linear (as, the value to be inserted is always greater than value at last index of sorted part). It become quadratic in worst case.